# Creating a categorical variable for sequence breaks in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with two columns for year and age, e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(year = 1980:2000, age = c(40:45, 31:40, 32:36))
```

I need to create a categorical variable that identifies each age sequence.  That would look something like this:

```
df$seq <- as.character(c(rep(1,6), rep(2,10), rep(3,5)))
```

Any ideas how to do this efficiently? I have managed to create a dummy for sequence breaks

```
require(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(brk = case_when(age - lag(age) != 1 ~ 1, T ~ 0)
```

but I'm struggling with filling in the rest.

Comment: Something like `cumsum(c(1, diff(df$age)) < 0) + 1` should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost done it already. You just need to create a cumulative sum (`cumsum`) of your `brk` column:

```
df %>% mutate(brk = cumsum(case_when(age - lag(age) != 1 ~ 1, T ~ 0)))
```

You can add 1 to the whole vector if you want to start the first sequence from 1 instead of 0.